# Why is the data not stored when using SubmitChanges?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Using MVC to create a database entry of type Player:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection fc, Player player)
{
    players.Players.InsertOnSubmit(player);
    players.SubmitChanges();

    Errors errors;
    if (!IsValid(player, out errors))
    {
        ViewBag.Errors = errors;
        return RedirectToAction("Edit", player);
    }

    return Redirect("/Home/Players");
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(FormCollection fc, Player player)
{
    players.SubmitChanges();

    return Redirect("/Home/Players");
}
```

My problem is that `players.SubmitChanges()` in the Edit method doesn't change anything in the database. Using `InsertObSubmit` in Create works. Shall I do it in another way?

Comment: `player` is not attached to the database. Also, this isn't related to MVC, but Linq-to-SQL or Entity Framework. :)

Comment: How and where should I attach player to the database? I would assume that it would know where it belonged since Player has the global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name) attribute set.

Answer (score 1):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(FormCollection fc, Player player)
{
    // I guess you are forgetting this
    players.Players.AttachAsModified(player)

    players.SubmitChanges();

    return Redirect("/Home/Players");
}
```

Comment: There is no such method in Players. Only Attach() and AttachAll(). If I use Attach() with asModified set to true I get the exception "System.InvalidOperationException: An entity can only be attached as modified without original state if it declares a version member or does not have an update check policy."

Comment: Can you try this, http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/11/27/attaching-modified-entities-in-ef-4.aspx ?

Answer (score 0):

When you get a Player value as input parameter for Edit action you should first modify your `players` collection accordingly - this won't happen automatically - and only then do `players.SubmitChanges();`

Comment: What do you mean by 'modify your players collection accordingly' ? How do I do that, in code?